# How does PartialClassGenerationTask and MarkupCompilePass1 works/belongs together

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, msbuild, baml

can some one explain how the two Build tasks `MarkupCompilePass1` and `PartialClassGenerationTask` belongs together? Currently I don't get whether they co-exists or if one needs each other. Can some one clearify the usage of both classes and how they might interact with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MarkupCompilePass1` will use the `PartialClassGenerationTask` to generate partial classes for all XAML files.

The WPF pipeline is pretty complex and there are many moving parts when compiling a WPF application.

The `PartialClassGenerationTask` acts specifically on XAML files that specify a type and have `x:Class`. When these are encountered the task will generate a matching cs or vb code file so the C#/VB compiler can reference the class and its properties later on.

The `MarkupCompilePass1` task turns a text based XAML file into a the binary BAML format. It will compile all XAML files that reference only types defined in other projects and referenced assemblies.

The `MarkupCompilePass2` task follows up on the Pass 1 and it specifically compiles XAML files which reference code in the same project to BAML.

To speed up compilation of your XAML projects it's better to define your types in a second project (standard Class Library). That way the `MarkupCompilePass2` can be skipped.

The full WPF build pipeline is explained on MSDN:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678(v=vs.100).aspx#The_Windows_Presentation_Foundation_Build_Pipeline

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation and the link!

Comment: I used `cs or vb code file so the C#/VB compiler can reference the class and its properties later on.` to compile xaml/create a partial class, but no properties are created. Do you have any hint here?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. A partial class is generated upon compilation. You'll be able to see what's generated by looking into the `obj` folder under your xaml project. Unless *your* classes are partial classes and specify the same namespace and classname, they won't be matched up.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  BTW, the updated location of the link is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/building-a-wpf-application-wpf